# NAT: Figuring out IP of broken down machine

Tags: nat, port-forwarding, network-traffic

I have a machine that was behind a natted router. Unfortunately its harddrive broke down, so I had to replace it. I have port 22 forwarded to it (in the router provided by the ISP) for remote management, but I don't know which IP

I have forgotten the admin password for the router (ISP's) so I was wondering whether I could set up some network traffic sniffing trying to capture the packets the router sends to the now defunct machine, to be able to assign the old Ip to the new machine.

I will of course still look for the password of the router to see if I can fix it the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You could try wireshark (windows, mac, linux) or the CLI version tcpdump (linux, Mac etc)

Connect the listening host to an ethernet port on the ISP router, and try to access with ssh to the NATed TCP port on the physical external port of the ISP router, and:

> *sudo tcpdump arp or icmp*
>
> `tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
>   listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
>   09:56:22.706193 ARP, Request who-has 10.200.255.178 tell 10.200.0.1, length 46`

Then You can see which IP address the ISP router will try to find in "who-has". In my example the IP address 10.200.0.1 is the inside IP of the ISP router.

If you use the graphical Wireshark, you need to set up a filter to catch only the arp and icmp messages. If there is only a few hosts on the internal network, you can run without filter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could I risk that the router filters out the packets since the ip is not up? and bonus: would there be ICMP packets in an SSH login request?

Comment: Q: How can the ISP router find out if the IP is UP?    A: By sending an ARP request.  " Request who-has x.x.x.x tell y.y.y.y"

ICMP = ping, if the router for some reasons would try ping also. The ISP router will not pass any SSH login until it has found that the IPaddress of the host is up.   ARP Request-->, ARP response<----, Optional PING (ICMP) --->,  PING response <---,   TCP session connect on port 22 --->, TCP Connect response <---   etc.

Comment: I will try it out. I only have very little wirechark/Tcpdump experience.

Comment: No problem, just keep the questions coming, and I'll try to help. Remember to "sudo" if your on a linux/mac host., so you can catch all packets on the network and not just your own.

Comment: My plan is to attempt it at my home network filtered on a specific known ip, where I can plug the network cable out of the machne, to see if i get the expected result, and then go try it out ITW

Comment: `tcpdump` is not a CLI version of `wireshark`. It's two completely different tools, which happen to have some overlap in functionality. In this particular question they would both be usable.